# How to attach google form to google spreadsheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to attach a google form to a google spreadsheet using the script, i went through the Spreadsheet documentation and i found a `getFormUrl()` function but no `setFormUrl()`, if someone could help me i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I did:

- I created Google Form,
- then added some scripts in it, to do stuff,
- and finally form returned responses == spreadsheet with answers from this form.

Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but if so, tell me, I'll give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the Google Form documentation and i found this :

```
// Open a form by ID and create a new spreadsheet.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Spreadsheet Name');

 // Update the form's response destination.
 form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
```

Works fine for me.